# display primary key after inserting in database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android app, and i want to display the primary key in the textview so that every-time I edit a textfield, I will be using the primary key to update.can anyone help me with this? below is the inserting of data in the  sqlite. My problem is how to get the primary key...

```java
public class UsedataActivity extends Activity {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    ImageButton evsave;
    EditText evname;
    EditText evtime;
    EditText evdate;
    EditText evcode;
    TextView evadmin;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_onetoone);

        evsave = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.event_save);
        evname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eventname);
        evtime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.time1);
        evdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eventdate);
        evcode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eventcode);
        evadmin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.adminname_1to1);

        evsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Events addev =
                    new Events(evname.getText().toString(),evcode.getText().toString(),evdate.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(evtime.getText().toString()),evadmin.getText().toString());

                db.addEvents(addev);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event:  "+ evname.getText()+" successfully save",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

database handler class:

```java
public void addEvents(Events event) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_EV_NAME, event.get_name());
    values.put(KEY_EV_PASS, event.get_pass());
    values.put(KEY_EV_DATE, event.get_date());
    values.put(KEY_EV_TIME, event.get_time());
    values.put(KEY_EV_ADMIN, event.get_admin());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: What is `DatabaseHandler` what does `addEvents` method do?

Comment: databasehandler is the class that i use to create the table and columns and addevent is a method in a class that will get the values inputed by the user

Comment: database handler class
public void addEvents(Events event) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(KEY_EV_NAME, event.get_name());
  values.put(KEY_EV_PASS, event.get_pass());
  values.put(KEY_EV_DATE, event.get_date());
  values.put(KEY_EV_TIME, event.get_time());
  values.put(KEY_EV_ADMIN, event.get_admin());
  
  // Inserting Row
  db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
  db.close();
 }

Comment: what codes can i add in the evsave.setclicklistener so that when the user press the button, as the data is save, it will also return the primary key in a textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it can be observed from the [docs for the SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29), `db.insert` will return the id of the newly created object. Just make `addEvents` return it (instead of being `void).

PS: Please paste code in edits of the question, not in comments. In comments they really look awful!

**EDIT**

```
public long addEvents(Events event) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_EV_NAME, event.get_name());
    values.put(KEY_EV_PASS, event.get_pass());
    values.put(KEY_EV_DATE, event.get_date());
    values.put(KEY_EV_TIME, event.get_time());
    values.put(KEY_EV_ADMIN, event.get_admin());
    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
    db.close();
    return id;
}
```

And then:

```
long id = db.addEvents(addev);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               "Event with id:  "+ id + " successfully saved",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @NicaSantos don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question.